# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression while querying a View with a subquery

Tags: oracle

I have a view as follows - It compiles just fine but when I try to select from it, I get a ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error. If I eliminate the subquery (column 4) from the view, all works fine. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

```
select
    l.LAB_GROUP,
    l.NAME as LAB,
    b.NAME as BENCH,
    (select count(distinct s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER)
    from SAMPLE s2 inner join TEST t2 on s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER = t2.SAMPLE_NUMBER and t2.STATUS            in ('C', 'R') and s2.TEMPLATE <> 'QC_SAMPLE'
    inner join LABORATORY_ENTRY le2 on t2.ANALYSIS = le2.ANALYSIS
    where s2.LAB_GROUP = l.LAB_GROUP and le2.NAME = l.NAME and t2.X_BENCH = b.NAME and
    ((select count(t1.TEST_NUMBER)
    from TEST t1
    where t1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = t2.SAMPLE_NUMBER and t1.ANALYSIS = t2.ANALYSIS and t1.STATUS   <> 'R') = 0)) as RFR
from LABORATORY l
inner join LABORATORY_ENTRY le on le.NAME = l.NAME 
inner join X_BENCH b on b.NAME = le.X_BENCH
left join (SAMPLE s inner join TEST t on s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = t.SAMPLE_NUMBER and s.STATUS <> 'U'
and s.TEMPLATE <> 'QC_SAMPLE' and t.STATUS in ('I', 'P')) on t.ANALYSIS = le.ANALYSIS and s.LAB_GROUP = l.LAB_GROUP
left join V_LOC_DEPT_FAC ldf on ldf.LOCATION_NUMBER = s.STORAGE_LOC_NO 
group by l.LAB_GROUP, l.NAME, b.NAME
```

Comment: as a side note you might want to consider a materialized view instead of the view as this looks like a costly query.

Comment: You don't appear to need the `GROUP BY` clause, since you don't have any aggregate functions as part of the select; the `COUNT` functions are in the subquery in column 4, not part of the main clause. But this would probably be easier to maintain if you move those subqueries to be joins instead...

Comment: Thanks .. The plan is to create a materialized view eventually.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use the group by (which will be the case if you add aggregating functions, but not as the query is currently written) you need to include the subquery in the `group by` as well. You can add this easiest by adding a `SELECT` outside your main query and appyling the `GROUP BY` at that level:

```
select lab_group, lab, bench, rfr
from 
(
   select
      l.LAB_GROUP as lab_group,
      l.NAME as LAB,
      b.NAME as BENCH,
      (select .....) as RFR
   from LABORATORY l
      inner join LABORATORY_ENTRY le on le.NAME = l.NAME 
      inner join X_BENCH b on b.NAME = le.X_BENCH
      left join (SAMPLE s inner join TEST t on ...) on 
          t.ANALYSIS = le.ANALYSIS and 
          s.LAB_GROUP = l.LAB_GROUP
      left join V_LOC_DEPT_FAC ldf on ldf.LOCATION_NUMBER = s.STORAGE_LOC_NO 
) x
group by lab_group, lab, bench, rfr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the...

```
group by l.LAB_GROUP, l.NAME, b.NAME
```

As I don't think this is neccesary if you're doing the count within the subquery.

However, for performance reasons I would suggest rewriting your query so that you move the subquery into the FROM section rather than the SELECT one.

Comment: Thank you ... My view is much bigger and it does contain certain counts because of which I need the group by. I had eliminated those lines for brevity. I agree, this is a costly view and we are in the process of tweaking it.